# Problem with Gmail messages missing headers

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, zend-mail, email-headers

I'm trying to programmatically parse my Gmail for various indexing functions, and am having trouble finding certain headers that I thought were standard email headers.  I'm using the Zend IMAP library, and have no problems with authentication and otherwise viewing/manipulating my Gmail.  However, I'm having trouble with some headers missing.  For instance

- about 1 out of 10 of the messages are missing the "message-id" header, including many sent from other gmail addresses
- occasionally, though rarely, the 'content-type','content-disposition', and 'filename' headers are missing from attachment headers.  These always seem to be messages that are part of a longer thread of messages.

Can anybody explain why these headers might be missing?  If the "message-id" header is missing, what is used as the unique identifier?  Perhaps some sort of combination of other headers?

Comment: Have you tried using telnet to check out if the message is incomplete ? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196748

Comment: No, but the message and the attachments display correctly in Gmail, and I can download the attachments just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6):

> The only required header fields are the origination date field and the originator address field(s).  All other header fields are syntactically optional.

The same RFC says:

> Though listed as optional in the table in section 3.6, every message SHOULD have a "Message-ID:" field.  Furthermore, reply messages SHOULD have "In-Reply-To:" and "References:" fields as appropriate and as described below.

So Message-ID isn't strictly-speaking mandatory. If it's missing, try looking for either the In-Reply-To or References fields.